# Recurring values in List<String> in Constructor java

Tags: java

**Sample.java**

```
public class Sample {


static List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

private String value;

private String type;

static List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();

public Item() throws ParseException {
    JsontoList j = new JsontoList();
    // types = Arrays.asList("green", "yellow", "red");
    array = j.getarray();
    list1 = j.toList(array);
    list = j.getList(array);
    types=list;

}

public List<String> getTypes() {
    return types;
}

//public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
    //this.types = types;
//}
```

With the above code..I am able to successfully display a Bootsfaces table.On click of **Add** commandbutton..**Textfields** and **Dropdown** are added in each column one by one and the input values are saved in JSON.
But the problem is..Whenever **ADD** is clicked.. alongwith the TextField and Dropdown..**the Dropdown values from database are also getting added each time resulting in many values.**

Though I tried not accessing the Dropdown values from database in Item Constructor.. but the values are not getting loaded in Webpage, except from within the Constructor.

Please suggest any other approach.Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou in advance.

Comment: In order to get correct answers/hints, I strongly recommend to reframe the question to show a [mcve] in form of a plain vanilla Java application with a `main()` method. Namely, this isn't a [jsf][bootsfaces] problem at all, but just basic [java].

Comment: I've been trying to get your example up and running for half an hour - to no avail. What do I have to compile your source codes? Which libraries do you use? And what are the `<tr />` tag for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution and this worked-

In **Item.java**

```
public Item() throws ParseException {
JsontoList j = new JsontoList();
array = j.getarray();
list1 = j.toList(array);
list = j.getList(array);

List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
types = list;

//Added this piece of code below

Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
// add elements to List types, including duplicates
hs.addAll(types);
types.clear();
types.addAll(hs);
}
```

For removing duplicates in a Collection, we should consider why we are using a Collection that allows duplicates. 
**The easiest way to remove repeated elements is to add the contents to a Set (which will not allow duplicates) and then add the Set back to the ArrayList.**

Comment: This will work until you ship your application. Once many users work with your application, you'll notice all kinds of strange errors. For instance, `types.addAll()` takes some time. If someone else reads the variable exactly at the same time, they will see only a part of the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess (because I don't know how to compile your source codes), but there's a very suspicious line. Have a look at the `@PostConstruct` method of `Item`. It initializes the **static** variable `types` over and over again. That's probably the line where the database is read and the result is added to the already-existing array `types`.

Generally, I recommend being very careful when using static variables. They only have to be initialized a single time. Actually, initializing static variables multiple times can cause all types of weird errors. You have to keep in mind that JSF applications are always used by many users. In other words, there are many threads accessing the one and only static variable. What happens if user A modifies the static variable user B has just read a second before? The minimum protection is a `synchronized` block together with a check whether the variable has already been initialized.

*Update Jan 10, 2017*: The resulting sourcecode looks roughly like so:

```
public class Item {
  private static List<String> types = null;

  public Item() throws ParseException {
    synchronized(types) {
      if (null==types) {
        JsontoList j = new JsontoList();
        String array = j.getarray();
        types = j.getList(array);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou... But can you please explain programmatically..how can I initialize **types** in **Item** only once without recurrence?

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation..:-) But the values are not getting loaded in dropdown by this process.

Comment: I can only guess, but I suspect that problem lies outside of the code snippet I suggested. Probably the constructor of `Item` is called before the Json list has been loaded from the database. Without having seen your code, I'd suggest a thorough debugging session in order to learn what happens in your code. After that, you'll probably want to tidy things up. At least that's what frequently happens to me when I run into similar situations.